# Cakephp 2.4 Auto Load Checked values for HABTM

Tags: cakephp, formhelper, cakephp-2.4

I cannot get the values to auto check. The list of options displays fine.

$this->data['Business']['ExpertiseType'] has values.

Business habtm ExpertiseType defined in all three models still set to their default bake.

Business belongsTo FormEoiEntry

```
$this->data = $this->FormEoiEntry->find('first', ['conditions'=>['FormEoiEntry.id'=>1324], 'recursive'=>2]);


$this->Form->create('FormEoiEntry');
$this->Form->input('Business.ExpertiseType', ['multiple'=>'checkbox']);
$this->Form->end();
```

Am I missing something here? I cannot figure out why it is not being detected and checking the boxes.

Answer (score 0):

set `expertise_types` from your controller like this.

```
$this->set('expertise_types', $this->FormEoiEntry->find('first', [
    'conditions'=>['FormEoiEntry.id'=>1324], 
    'recursive'=>2,
]);
```

and in your view

```
$this->Form->input('Business.ExpertiseType', [
    'options' => $expertise_types,
    'multiple'=>'checkbox'
]);
```

**update**

In that case pass the selected options values to the `$this->request->data['Business']['ExpertiseType']`

just like this

```
$this->request->data['Business']['ExpertiseType'] = array(
    'select option value 1', // you can put your option values
    'select option value 2',
    'select option value 3',
    'select option value 4',
);
```

Comment: $expertise_types should be $expertiseTypes as per convention

Comment: Yes, i agreed but i'm setting options here in view which does the same thing

Comment: I don't think this would return the correct results. Why query FormEoiEntry for ExpertiseType options? I did test this and I got a whole bunch of random options. My problem is not loading the options, just loading the selected values. I am already setting the options via find('list'). Does it have something to do with the format of the returned list?

Comment: In that case pass the selected options values to the `$this->request->data['Business']['ExpertiseType'] `